# restrict access on php file from all except one file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this file structure .

```
index.php
includes
        functions.php
```

in the `index.php` file i call `functions.php` use ajax.i want to block access to `functions.php` from all except from `index.php` .if someone know directory name of `functions.php` and want to access to this file the error occur .I want to do this with `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to:

1. In your index.php before echoing javascript, construct a one time key.
2. Send that key to your functions.php, if key is valid then process.

I wouldn't rely on referral URL or anything less secure.

Comment: That will not work if the file is called using ajax (that's how I read the question at least...).

Comment: <FilesMatch "functions.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @adib16 If you block using `.htaccess`, you will not be able to call it using ajax, only as an include.

Comment: if i use the above code how i can Specify access to functions.php only for index.php ??

Comment: @adib16 If you use htacces you will not be able to access it via PHP. There is no way for htaccess to restrict access differentiating Ajax calls from regular calls. Additionally, you need to make sure that the call is valid. Constructing a key only you know is the safest, even if someone duplicates your ajax functionality it won't work for them since they don't know how to construct the key.